# How can I fix '<app_name> keeps stopping' error in android?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I am struggling with the error which shows ' keeps stopping' error on android emulator. I searched the source of the error and I find that whenever I add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' this line at app level build gradle, my app keeps stopping. But If I do not add that line I can not use firebase anymore. How can I solve this problem?Could you help me please? Thank you in advance.

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.instagram_clone"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0"
implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')


} 


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //this line creates error
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an emulator there are some that supports google and some that not. Make sure you create an emulator that is compatible with Google Play Services.

[This column shows Google Play compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ZWx.png)

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer. I tried differents emulator but I could not fixed the error. By the way I cano not see the image which you wrote your answer.